# Clean Custom URL for Serach + Custom Taxonomy

Tags: custom-taxonomy, url-rewriting, search, urls

I have a custom taxonomy, called `filter`. All of the following urls lead to the `archive.php` and should give me at least 1 post.

- `/filter/bar` works by default, no custom rule needed
- `/myCategory/filter/bar` works with my own custom rule, nice!
- `/search/foo` works by my custom rule
- `/?s=foo&filter=bar` works as expected
- **`/search/foo/filter/bar`** **BOOM!** No entries

Here are my rules:

```
add_filter("rewrite_rules_array", function($rules) {

    $newRules = array();

    // ... more rules

    $newRules["search/(.+)/?$"] = 'index.php?s=$matches[1]';

    $newRules["search/(.*)/filter/(.*)/?$"] = 'index.php?s=$matches[1]&filter=$matches[2]';

    $merged = array_merge($newRules, $rules);

    return $merged;
});
```

---

**EDIT**

Query-Monitor for the desired URL
(suche = search in german)

[image]

Comment: Try using https://wordpress.org/plugins/query-monitor/ which will tell you which rewrite is being matched.

Comment: Thank you for the tip– I edited my post and added a screenshot of a query-monitor analysis of the situation. Appreciate some further help!

Comment: Jeez– big thanks for this plugin; huge helper in general; quick question though: I can't make much sense of the MySQL queries; is there a way to see what $wp_query looks like? or see all the query vars?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Slam's kind tip to use [query-monitor plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/query-monitor/), I could figure out what the problem was.

Apparently the url `/search/foo/filter/bar` also fits the "general search" rewrite-rule. Makes sense, thinking about it– `(.+)` technically matches `/foo/filter/bar` aswell. So I could improve `(.+)` by excluding `/`s?

But I found an easier solution!

In hope "first match wins" I declared the more specific rule before the general rule– and e voila, it worked!

```
add_filter("rewrite_rules_array", function($rules) {

    $newRules = array();

    // more specific rule first
    $newRules["search/(.*)/filter/(.*)/?$"] = 'index.php?s=$matches[1]&filter=$matches[2]';

    // general rule later
    $newRules["search/(.+)/?$"] = 'index.php?s=$matches[1]';

    $merged = array_merge($newRules, $rules);

    return $merged;
});
```

Comment: I thought that would be the problem. Glad Query Monitor worked out for you!

Comment: Yeah it did! Thanks very much :) – Can you tell me if there is a way to see the actual `$wp_query` with Query-Monitor? I can't make that much use of the DB queries, to be honest :o